# pywin32 and pyttsx error, trouble combining the two

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, pyttsx

i have pywin32 in my site packages and my pyttsx is in a separate folder. Is this the reason why i am getting the following error?

```
import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

The code is as follows,

```
import pyttsx
def onStart(name):
    print 'starting', name
def onWord(name, location, length):
    print 'word', name, location, length
def onEnd(name, completed):
    print 'finishing', name, completed
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.connect('started-utterance', onStart)
engine.connect('started-word', onWord)
engine.connect('finished-utterance', onEnd)
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

from here, http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/engine.html#examples

My pywin32 is from here,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

for Py 2.7

Comment: I don't think the 2 are related. How did you install _pywin32_? can you point to the exact version (you probably downloaded)? Also, what's the exact _Python_ version you're running (just copy paste the 1st line printed after you start the interpreter)?

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question for you. I am using the amd64 for py2.7

Comment: Ok, a little bit of debug is needed (I assume that both _Python_ and _pywin_ installations __went successfully__). First: determine which module triggers the error (99% it's `win32api`). Separate your import statement in 3 separate imports to see which one is responsible for the error. Now search in your  `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32`('C:\Windows\System32`) folder for `pywintypes27.dll` (or anything similar).

Comment: thank you, but in my C:\Windows\System32 folder I could find no such pywintypes27.dll file. Is this good or bad?

Comment: Then either your _pywin_ installation is corrupt, either you installed the 32bit version. You can check if it's the latter  by checking if `pywintypes27.dll` is present in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: great, you helped me. I had the file, however it was not in the C:\Windows\System32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the file

```
pywintypes27.dll
```

was not in the right directory. It had to be in

```
'C:\Windows\System32'
```

@CristiFati

Answer (score 0):

Use the **pyttsx3** module instead . It supports both python3 and python2.

To install:

`pip install pyttsx3`.

It automatically installs those win32 and other dependencies.